# print empty line into file with bash

Tags: bash, file, echo

I want to print an empty line in a file. Not just a line break after an input but a whole empty line.

How do I do that?

Currently I'm printing content to a file in the following way:

```
echo -e "objectClass: inetOrgPerson" >> $filenamecombined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `printf` and insert `\n`s to add newlines where necessary:

```
printf 'objectClass: inetOrgPerson\n\n' >> "$filenamecombined"
```

`echo -e` might also work on your system but it is non-standard.